# SSIS Excel Write To Variable writes 0 rows

Tags: excel, vba, variables, ssis, export

Sorry if this is a bit of a noob question but I'm not all that good with vb and I've been googling my issue all week and not finding a solution.

I'm trying to export a weekly data extract from SQL Server 2008 to a new (variably named) worksheet in an Excel workbook using SSIS.

My current set up is a script task that defines the excel sheet name to write to followed by an ODBC -> Excel transfer.

This is my script task (which passeses debugging every time);

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim vars As Variables
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("SheetName", vars)
    vars(0).Value = "Week_" & DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Today())
    vars.Unlock()

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success


End Sub
```

I've got my user variable, SheetName, set to Package-wide with the Value set to WeekNew.

I have the package set to run in 32bit.
I've set the delay validation to True for the entire contents of container.

I was getting these error messages in the debug log yesterday;

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at Create Data Extract, Create Extract [804]: 
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
Error: 0xC02020E8 at Create Data Extract, Create DQ Extract [804]: 
Opening a rowset for "Week_30" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
Error: 0xC004701A at Create Data Extract, SSIS.Pipeline: component "Create Extract" (804) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.
```

I can't remember what I changed yesterday, but now when it gets to the Excel Destination part of the export I get the following from the debug log;

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at Create Data Extract, Excel Destination [1045]: SSIS Error Code
DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
Error: 0xC02020E8 at Create Data Extract, Excel Destination [1045]: Opening a rowset for "Week_30" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
Error: 0xC004701A at Create Data Extract, SSIS.Pipeline: component "Excel Destination" (1045) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.
```

I really don't know what to do to fix this and it's starting to drive me nuts. Any advice anyone can give would be amazing, I am so out of my depth right now!

EDIT: I have tried creating the destiation in the excel file and writing to that but it still writes 0 rows.

EDIT: Having followed the tutorial that TMNT2014 posted, I've gotten the following error messages;

```
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 1 to variable "User::WeekKey" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 8 to variable "User::Ref_Number" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 9 to variable "User::Ref_Number_2" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 10 to variable "User::Ref_Number3" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 11 to variable "User::Ref_Number4" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 13 to variable "User::Status1" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 14 to variable "User::Status2" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 22 to variable "User::Region" cannot be applied.
Error: 0xC001C012 at Foreach Loop Container: ForEach Variable Mapping number 45 to variable "User::Date" cannot be applied.
```

There are 45 fields in my dataset, these are the only errors I'm getting and there's no additional info. I've checked online and haven't found anyone else that is JUST getting the variable mapping error (it's always in conjunction with something else) and no-one has had this issue using Rafael's example data. I can only assume that it's something to do with the source formatting of my data.

I have all 45 variables set to String, the create table statement creates each field as Varchar and I have a data conversion from Unicode string to non-unicode string in the export (because otherwise it fails on conversion). Any ideas?

Comment: So essentially you have the variable name for the excel sheet name set up properly but it actually does not exist in the destination file. Hence the error, you would need to create the Table(sheet) in the destination. Here is something I found while googling - http://www.rafael-salas.com/2006/12/import-header-line-tables-_116683388696570741.html. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried making the destination sheet as well, sorry I forgot to mention that. When I have the destination sheet in the file it still writes 0 rows. I'm looking at the link, this might work :) Thank you, I'll let you know if it does!

Comment: Sorry, unless I'm doing soething wrong, it doesn't work for worksheets in an excel file the way it does for the excel workbooks.

Comment: Still having issues? So does the code for creating the destination sheet work for you? I mean can you open the excel file and see that your destination spreadsheet has Week_30? Also in the sheetname variable you would want to set it as  - vars(0).Value = "Week_" & DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Today())&"$"

Comment: I've followed the instructions in the blog and I'm getting a new error now. I'll post it in the OP.

Comment: Ehhh.. you are overly complicating your task by using the for each record. Could you back up a bit? Hopefully you have a copy of your original package and in your earlier comment "I've tried making the destination sheet as well, sorry I forgot to mention that. When I have the destination sheet in the file it still writes 0 rows. " So if you have the code to create the destination sheet in place then can you just try to see if it works by changing your variable value to include the "$" sign at the end?  - vars(0).Value = "Week_" & DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Today())&"$"

Comment: Ah right, OK. Sorry. Variables are a really new thing for me (I've only started looking at them since I started building this package) so I just followed the instructions to the letter in case I'd miss something important otherwise. I will load up my old ver package and try what you have suggested later today.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the config that I have used (and it works, I've checked!)

*In a Sequence Container:*
**vb.net Script Task**

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim vars As Variables
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("SheetName", vars)
    vars(0).Value = "Week_" & DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Today())&"$"
    vars.Unlock()

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Entry Point = Main
No variables

**Then a Data Flow Task**
Made up of
OLEDB Source - Table or View
Data Conversion - Non Unicode to Unicode
Excel Destination - Table Name or Sheet Variable (User::SheetName)

The Variables I have in the package are:
**CreateSheetStatement** - Pretty sure this isn't being used any more but keeping it just in case I need it in future.
I've taken the Create table statement out due to data sensitivity, but you get the jist

```
"CREATE TABLE `"+ @[User::SheetName] + "`(ENTER CREATE TABLE STATEMENT HERE)"
```

**SheetName**

```
(DT_WSTR,5)"Week_" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("week", getdate() )+"$"
```

**XLFileRootDir**
This one is used to define the datestamp at the end of the variable file name in the excel connection manager

In Excel, I've created the tabs for each Week Key and defined a named range on each tab which relates to the tab name (So, Tab Week_01 has a Named range for my data to land in which is called Week_01)

Thank you for all your help TMNT2014! :)

Comment: Yep! :) Thank you so much for your help and your patience!